# Why won't my recursive DNS resolver resolve this domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am using bind9 as a recursive resolver and it works beautifully for 99% of domains.

However it returns an NXDOMAIN for this one `michaelkors.scene7.com` even though some public nameservers [return an answer](https://www.nslookup.io/dns-records/michaelkors.scene7.com#cloudflare) for it.

What is curious is that in the linked online DNS utility, some servers report one IP, others another IP, and the authoritative servers don't return any records at all.

It seems like the nameservers for this domain are misconfigured, but then how come Google and Cloudflare are returning results? Are they perhaps just returning cached results?

What can one do in situations like this?

*Update:* It looks as if my bind is trying to use their IPV6 nameservers.

Problem is I don't have IPV6 connectivity.  How does one turn this off in bind9?

```
13-Sep-2021 15:41:52.907 queries: client @0x8233e3000 192.168.1.4#33106 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query: michaelkors.scene7.com IN A +E(0) (192.168.1.4)
13-Sep-2021 15:41:53.299 lame-servers: host unreachable resolving 'ns201.adobe.net/A/IN': 2001:502:8cc::30#53
...
13-Sep-2021 15:41:53.301 lame-servers: host unreachable resolving 'ns204.adobe.net/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:d937::30#53
13-Sep-2021 15:41:53.409 query-errors: client @0x8233e3000 192.168.1.4#33106 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for michaelkors.scene7.com/IN/A at query.c:8678
13-Sep-2021 15:41:53.414 queries: client @0x824194000 192.168.1.22#61146 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query: michaelkors.scene7.com IN A + (192.168.1.4)
13-Sep-2021 15:41:53.414 query-errors: client @0x824194000 192.168.1.22#61146 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for michaelkors.scene7.com/IN/A at query.c:7118
```

*Update 2:* After disabling IPV6 with the `-4` flag, I am still unable to resolve that domain.  Here is the log output now:

```
3-Sep-2021 16:09:18.392 queries: client @0x823293a00 192.168.1.22#51775 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query: michaelkors.scene7.com IN A + (192.168.1.4)
13-Sep-2021 16:09:18.394 query-errors: client @0x823293a00 192.168.1.22#51775 (michaelkors.scene7.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for michaelkors.scene7.com/IN/A at query.c:8678
13-Sep-2021 16:09:18.395 queries: client @0x823293000 192.168.1.22#58047 (michaelkors.scene7.com.localnet): query: michaelkors.scene7.com.localnet IN A + (192.168.1.4)
```

Comment: My bind9 resolves it. Probably something wrong on your side. What to do? First, use public DNS Looking Glass (there are lots of them in the Internet) to check if it's only you or everybody.

Comment: Did you look at the logfiles (and increase verbosity) of your own recursive nameserver to see why it think `NXDOMAIN`? You can look at https://dnsviz.net/d/michaelkors.scene7.com/YT9hzQ/dnssec/ for troubleshooting your record seems fine, albeit depending on a zone that is in a lame delegation situation.

Comment: See above. I *think* my resolver is trying to connect to their IPV6 nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

I am blocking some zones using an adblock blacklist.

When I disable that blacklist, the domain resolves fine.

It still isn't obvious which blocked domain is causing the problem, probably one of the dozens of `*.edgekey.net` entries in the list.  I can sort this out later.

The one good thing is that it alerted me to the fact that I needed to disable IPV6.

Comment: Eh? IPv6 is completely irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: Yes, IPV6 was not the cause, but while debugging this problem I noticed that my nameserver was trying to connect to IPV6 namservers which would always fail.